# Understanding variable scoping with async statements

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

When I do the following:

```
for (var CurrentRow=0;CurrentRow < qryMfg.RecordCount;CurrentRow++){
    console.log(qryMfg.MFGID[CurrentRow]);
    dbo.transaction(function(myTrans) {
        console.log(qryMfg.MFGID[CurrentRow]);
    });
}
```

I get a list of MfgID the way that I want, followed by a list of unknowns because `dbo.transaction` is executing asynchronously.

How do I pass a variable into `dbo.transaction`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable scope is created in functions, so create a function that returns the handler...

```
function create_handler( scoped_row ) {
    return function(myTrans) {
        console.log(qryMfg.MFGID[scoped_row]);
    };
}
```

...and invoke it in the loop, passing it whatever you need scoped, in this case, the `CurrentRow`...

```
for (var CurrentRow=0;CurrentRow < qryMfg.RecordCount;CurrentRow++) {
    console.log(qryMfg.MFGID[CurrentRow]);
    dbo.transaction( create_handler(CurrentRow) );
}
```

Now each individual handler is created in the same unique scope that was created via the invocation in each iteration.

Since the `CurrentRow` was passed into that function scope, each handler will reference the unique value in its own scope via the `scoped_row` parameter.

When the handler is returned from the function, it will be passed to the `dbo.transaction`.

Even though it is passed out of the function where it was created, it will retain its original variable scope, and so will always have access to the `scoped_row` parameter.

---

You could also put the whole operation in the function if you prefer.

```
function create_transaction( scoped_row ) {
    console.log(qryMfg.MFGID[scoped_row]);

    dbo.transaction( function(myTrans) {
        console.log(qryMfg.MFGID[scoped_row]);
    });
}
```

...which will have the same outcome as long as you pass it the `CurrentRow`...

```
for (var CurrentRow=0;CurrentRow < qryMfg.RecordCount;CurrentRow++) {
    create_transaction( CurrentRow );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how myTrans is getting created.  Does dbo.transaction pass myTrans to create_handler?

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn: `myTrans` is a parameter to the callback function. When the `dbo.transaction` eventually calls your callback, it passes some value as the first argument, which you can reference via the `myTrans` parameter. So in short, you don't need to worry about setting its value. The caller of the function sets it.

Comment: I appreciate you explaining this further.  Your last example helped a little more.

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn: Glad it helped. To make it a little more clear, I changed the name of the parameter in the function to `scoped_row` in order to demonstrate that it's actually different from the original.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (var CurrentRow=0;CurrentRow < qryMfg.RecordCount;CurrentRow++) {
    console.log(qryMfg.MFGID[CurrentRow]);

    (function(row) {
        dbo.transaction(function(myTrans) {
            console.log(qryMfg.MFGID[row]);
        }); 
    })(CurrentRow);
}
```

Comment: Ah.  You're creating a self executing function and passing CurrentRow in as the parameter.  Thanks!